# Ionic 4 sliding-item getSlidingRatio is not a function

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, ionic4

I'm trying to use (ionDrag) directive to increment or decrement an amount, so i created a view that looks like :

```
<ion-item-sliding (ionDrag)="handleSlide($event, tour)">
  <ion-item>
    Drag to add or remove
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item-options side="start">
    <ion-item-option><ion-icon name="remove-circle-outline"></ion-icon></ion-item-option>
  </ion-item-options>

  <ion-item-options side="end">
    <ion-item-option><ion-icon name="add-circle-outline"></ion-icon></ion-item-option>
  </ion-item-options>
</ion-item-sliding>
```

In the controller, i write this code :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-places',
  templateUrl: './places.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./places.component.scss']
})
export class PlacesComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() tour: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public handleSlide(event: any, tour: any): void {

    const percent: Number = event.getSlidingRatio();

    console.log('Slide ' + event.type + ' : ' + percent);
    if (percent > 0) {
      this.increment();
    } else {
      this.decrement();
    }
  }

  private increment(): any {
    console.log('Up');
  }

  private decrement(): any {
    console.log('Down');
  }
}
```

But when i drag the element, console returns a TypeError e.getSlidingRatio is not a function.

I'm using Ionic 4 and replace getSlidingPercent with getSlidingRatio according to the update docs.

Try to hint the event as CustomEvent but... getSlidingRatio() doesn't exists on this type... same thing with CustomEvent

So my question... What i'm doing wrong with this piece of code ?

Comment: According to https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/components/item-sliding/item-sliding.tsx#L286 you should access `event.ratio`

Comment: Thx... But, event.ratio value seems to be undefined... as well as amount... Just replace my console to see what contains 'event' and get {"isTrusted": false}, so, i think 'event' is not transmitted as expected

Answer (score 1):

I had some issues with the same, when in one of the beta versions I couldn't get access to this at all, but in the latest version (4.0.0 / 4.0.1) still needs a workaround, at least for me. My versioning is:

```
"@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
"@ionic/angular": "^4.0.0",

ionic cli: 4.10.2
```

With that, pass the event as like you do, but I found the followig [issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/16560) I needed to hack into `details`. So when console.logging the `$event`, it outputs includes an object `details`, with the `ratio` property, so this solved my issue:

```html
<ion-item-sliding (ionDrag)="handleSlide($event)">
  <!-- ... -->
</ion-item-sliding>
```

TS:

```ts
handleSlide(event: any) {    
  let ratio = event.detail.ratio;
  console.log(ratio);
}
```

Check your versioning and hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1):

ion-item-sliding's [getSlidingRatio](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item-sliding) method returns a promise, so you cannot assign it directly to a variable.

```js
handleSlide(event, tour) {
    event.target.getSlidingRatio().then(res => {
        let ratio = res;
        console.log(ratio);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First: in the HTML you have to put an alias `#sliding` to your ion-item-sliding

Second: in your TS just after the export line use the `ViewChild`:

```
  @ViewChild('sliding', { static: false }) sliding: IonItemSliding;

  // {static: false} make the difference
```

Third: in your function uses the `getSlidingRatio()` method

```
    this.sliding.getSlidingRatio()
   .then( val => {
     console.log({val});
   })
   .catch(err => {
     console.log({err});
   });
```